# Usability testing tool with Screen Upload and Prototyping feature

Tags: software-testing, user-interface, prototyping, usability-testing

I'm working at a big company in the UX/UI department and am currently looking for a Usability-testing tool for my Figma Mock-Ups.

I'll jump straight to the problem at hand: We do not have the "power" to share Figma Prototype Links "with anyone", meaning we cannot use most features of etablished user testing tools. **Therefore I am looking for a provider, that lets us upload and prototype screens (like ProtoPie) and also lets us evaluate the flow of these (like a.e. UseBerry).**

Some of the services I looked at but didn't have the option to just upload screens:

- UserTesting
- UserBrain
- Maze
- Lyssna
- UXTweak
- UseBerry (our previous Method to work with until we found out we can't use heatmaps without "anyone can access this link")

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated. I thought about programming a webtool myself just for this purpose that's how desperate I am.

Features I am looking for:

- A/B Testing,
- Preference Testing,
- Prototype Testing,
- Some evaluation tools like a Heatmap